# Datagridview won't refresh after deleting a record from database

Tags: c#, winforms

Why won't it refresh?

```
private void deleteRecord()
        {
            if (BooksGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedIndex = BooksGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                int rowID = int.Parse(BooksGrid[0, selectedIndex].Value.ToString());
                string sql = "DELETE FROM Books WHERE BookID = @RowID";

                SqlCommand deleteRecord = new SqlCommand();
                deleteRecord.Connection = Booksconnection;
                deleteRecord.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                deleteRecord.CommandText = sql;

                SqlParameter RowParameter = new SqlParameter();
                RowParameter.ParameterName = "@RowID";
                RowParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                RowParameter.IsNullable = false;
                RowParameter.Value = rowID;

                deleteRecord.Parameters.Add(RowParameter);

                deleteRecord.Connection.Open();

                deleteRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();

                deleteRecord.Connection.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the record has actually been deleted from the database?

Comment: Why *would* it refresh? There's no code there to reload the the data, nor update the existing datasource for your `DataGridView`

Comment: If I relaunch the program the record's gone. So it deletes the record from database for sure.

Comment: @Rowland I tried to use Dataset's GetChanges() and then refilling the sqldataadapter with dataset.table as a parameter but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what your `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` is, (and assuming the record has actually been deleted from the database) I would say you need to reset the `DataSource`, whatever it may be.

For example, in my code, I usually have a `DataTable` as my `DataSource` and then I call `DataTable.Clear()` to clear it out. Afterwards, I fill it back up with the database.  This ensures my `DataGridView` has a fully updated `DataTable` as its `DataSource`.

Comment: I don't have DataTable I have this: 
BooksGrid.DataSource = booksDataset1.Books;
sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(booksDataset1.Books);

Comment: @User DataSets still have the Clear() method.

Answer (score 0):

`Dataset.GetChanges()` will only work when you've made the changes via the dataset - in this case you're doing it outside of its control, so you're going to have to actually reload the dataset yourself (or better still, call the method that populated it in the first place) - this way, you'll pick up changes from other users too...

Comment: I did the same thing with add button but it refreshes properly after adding a record. With GetChanges() and SqlAdapeter.Fill(dataset.table) that is.

Comment: @User you must've done *something* different, as if you did the same, that would try to delete a record. I'd suspect the "add" does something completely different, as it would need additional information